# asp.net textbox and enter key

Tags: asp.net, html, button, textbox, enter

I have a couple of `<div>`s with separate asp:textbox and asp:button.

What I need to do is make sure that the correct button gets clicked in the correct `<div>` when the user hits enter.

Without using asp:panel, defaultbutton.

What is the quickest way to do that?

Comment: Why not use ASP panel control?  All of this is already handled for you then.

Comment: Does user Hit  enter in textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by setting the default button using javascript on each div like that :

```
$('div').keypress( function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == '13') {
     $(this).find('.acceptEnter').click();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET **Panel Control** & set the **DefaultButton** Property.

[Panel.DefaultButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):
Use the DefaultButton property to indicate which button gets clicked when the Panel control has focus and the user presses the ENTER key. The DefaultButton can be set to the identifier for a Button control or any control that implements the IButtonControl interface except a LinkButton control.